# center day variable at final observation in R (for linear mixed model)

Tags: r, mixed-models

I'm trying to analyze some data with repeated measurements on subjects in different treatment groups.  Here's a subset of my data with observations taken on days 1, 3, and 21 (the complete dataset has additional observations on days between 3 and 21).

```
mydata <- data.frame(
  Subject  = c(13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 
           34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 62, 63, 64, 65, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
           19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 
           40, 62, 63, 64, 65, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 
           29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 62, 63, 64, 65), 
  Day       = as.numeric(c(rep(c("1", "3", "21"), each=28))), 
  Treatment = c(rep(c("B", "A", "C", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B", "A", "C", "B", "C", 
                  "A", "A", "B", "A", "C", "B", "C", "A", "A"), each = 4)), 
  Obs       = c(6.472687, 7.017110, 6.200715, 6.613928, 6.829968, 7.387583, 7.367293, 
            8.018853, 7.527408, 6.746739, 7.296910, 6.983360, 6.816621, 6.571689, 
            5.911261, 6.954988, 7.624122, 7.669865, 7.676225, 7.263593, 7.704737, 
            7.328716, 7.295610, 5.964180, 6.880814, 6.926342, 6.926342, 7.562293, 
            6.677607, 7.023526, 6.441864, 7.020875, 7.478931, 7.495336, 7.427709, 
            7.633020, 7.382091, 7.359731, 7.285889, 7.496863, 6.632403, 6.171196, 
            6.306012, 7.253833, 7.594852, 6.915225, 7.220147, 7.298227, 7.573612, 
            7.366550, 7.560513, 7.289078, 7.287802, 7.155336, 7.394452, 7.465383, 
            6.976048, 7.222966, 6.584153, 7.013223, 7.569905, 7.459185, 7.504068, 
            7.801867, 7.598728, 7.475841, 7.511873, 7.518384, 6.618589, 5.854754, 
            6.125749, 6.962720, 7.540600, 7.379861, 7.344189, 7.362815, 7.805802, 
            7.764172, 7.789844, 7.616437, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

I want to analyze my data using a linear mixed model (using nlme):

```
mymodel <- lme(Obs ~ Treatment * Day, random = ~1 | Subject, correlation = corAR1(form = ~1 | Subject), data=mydata, na.action=na.omit)
```

Since I'm most interested in differences on the final day of the experiment, I'd really like the center at Day 21, but R appears to use the the lowest value as the reference level for a numerical variable.  I could just set Day 21 to 0, but that messes up the time sequence, which is important for the autocorrelation structure, and changing Day to a factor just gives me an error message:

Error in MEEM(object, conLin, control$niterEM) : 
  Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1

So, how do I test the effect of Treatment with Day 21 as the reference level of Day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
mydata$Day = relevel(mydata$Day, ref="Day21")
```

before you run your model. (I think in your model `Subject` should be written instead of `Sample`), at least for your example, because there is no `Sample` in `mydata`.

**EDIT**

the original example has been edited, but the same approach should still work:

```
mydata$Day = factor(mydata$Day, levels=c(21, 3, 1))


mymodel <- lme(Obs ~ Treatment * Day, random = ~1 | Subject, correlation = 
                corAR1(form = ~1 | Subject), data=mydata, na.action=na.omit)
summary(mymodel)
```

which gives:

```
Fixed effects: Obs ~ Treatment * Day 
Value Std.Error DF  t-value p-value
(Intercept)      7.635586 0.1159703 46 65.84086  0.0000
TreatmentB      -0.965811 0.1682325 25 -5.74093  0.0000
TreatmentC      -0.169050 0.1682325 25 -1.00486  0.3246
Day3            -0.208276 0.1133072 46 -1.83815  0.0725
Day1            -0.452858 0.1306224 46 -3.46693  0.0012
TreatmentB:Day3  0.229415 0.1636327 46  1.40201  0.1676
TreatmentC:Day3  0.060868 0.1636327 46  0.37198  0.7116
TreatmentB:Day1  0.352958 0.1932224 46  1.82669  0.0742
TreatmentC:Day1  0.334850 0.1932224 46  1.73298  0.0898
```

Comment: Sorry, I used an old version of my dataframe by mistake; `Day` should be numeric, and it should be `Subject`, not `Sample`.  Edited to correct that.

Comment: The issue is that, since `Day` is numeric, `relevel()` doesn't work.

Comment: But if it is numeric, how do you want to specify a 'reference level'? Why don't you simply convert it to a factor and define 21 as the reference level?

Comment: Perhaps my terminology is wrong?  What I mean is, when you say `summary(mymodel)`, you get an output for the fixed effects:  `(Intercept)`, `TreatmentB`, `TreatmentC`, etc.  My understanding is that the value for `TreatmentB` is the difference between `TreatmentB` and `TreatmentA` on the first "level" of day (in my case, day 1).  If I want to see that for day 21 instead, I'm not sure what to do; if I do `mydata$Day <- as.factor(mydata$Day)` and then `lme(Obs ~ Treatment*Day, ...` all I get is the error message I mentioned in my original post.

Comment: what kind or error message? I edited the answer with the data that you provided, and it just works fine

Comment: You're right, of course, this works fine with the data I provided; turns out there's a problem with the data from day 9 (too many missing measurements, I suspect) that causes it to give the following error: `Error in MEEM(object, conLin, control$niterEM) : 
  Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1`.  So, I guess no day 9 data for me!  But otherwise, much better.  Thanks!